# Customer filter pipe - Angular2

Tags: html, forms, angular, angular-pipe

In the below component view,

```
<h2>Topic listing</h2>

<form id="filter">
  <label>Filter topics by name:</label>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term">
</form>

<ul id="topic-listing">
  <li *ngFor="let topic of topics | filter: term">
    <div class="single-topic">
      <!-- Topic name -->
      <span [ngStyle]="{background: 'yellow'}">name - {{topic.name}}</span>
      <!-- Topic type -->
      <h3>{{topic.type}}</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Custom filter syntax is: `let topic of topics | filter: term`

where custom filter is:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(topics: any, term: any): any {
    // check if search term is undefined
    if(term === undefined) return topics;
    return topics.filter(function(topic){ // javascript filter(function)
      // if below is false, then topic will be removed from topics array
      return topic.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
    })
  }

}
```

---

the component class maintains data for `topics`:

```
export class DirectoryComponent implements OnInit {
  topics = [
    {type:"Fiction", name:"Avatar"},
    {type:"NonFiction", name:"Titanic"},
    {type:"Tragedy", name:"MotherIndia"},
  ];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

---

**Edit:** Without `form` tag, code works fine.

```
  <label>Filter topics by name:</label>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term">
```

---

Why custom filter `FilterPipe` does not filter `term` provided in input element?

Comment: post your complete code with pipe name

Comment: @Sajeetharan Which code is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add brackets to your filter condition

```
<ul id="topic-listing">
  <li *ngFor="let topic of (topics | filter: term)">
    <div class="single-topic">
      <!-- Topic name -->
      <span [ngStyle]="{background: 'yellow'}">name - {{topic.name}}</span>
      <!-- Topic type -->
      <h3>{{topic.type}}</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Check the TS file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  term : any = "avatar";
  topics = [
    {type:"Fiction", name:"Avatar"},
    {type:"NonFiction", name:"Titanic"},
    {type:"Tragedy", name:"MotherIndia"},
  ];
}
```

Remove the word function and change it to below code. refer the [working version here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4mae57)

```
return topics.filter((topic)=>{ 
      return topic.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
    })
```

**update - root cause of the issue**

if you want to use NgModel inside the form tags, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions

Comment: edited my answer. I am exactly don't know why it's not working with word function.

Comment: Your StackBlitz example works with the `function` keyword also, so it must be something else that's different.

Comment: @serpent5 With lambda expression it does not work for me

Comment: That's what I expected. Closely compare what you have with @PrithiviRaj's example and see what the difference is.

Comment: I also did one change in HTML. Please try this and let me know

Comment: See my working version and compare as @serpent5 said

Comment: Only your form is not placed in the working version. check that too.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, where is the search option to search the `term` with an `ngModel`?`<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term">`

Comment: I did not mention `term : any;` in component class

Comment: Hard coding a value to `term` is not a right idea. `term:any;`

Comment: change it to string then

Comment: I changed that too in that link. it's working there. what you are trying to do?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/shamhub/Front-end-programming/tree/master/Angular-2/src) is my complete code

Comment: remove the form tag if you are not using angular forms. after removing the form tag it's started working. I copied that code to my working version. check and let me know

Comment: Yes, form tag is creating problem. Any reason for that? Now it is working without form tag. Please update the answer accordingly.

Comment: if you use form tags, you will get the following error message in console "If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions."